# Plain JS onclick button Best Practice

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 buttons who throw a plain JS function (i dont want to use Jquery) but i'm asking what is the **Best Practice** between these methods :

```js
function next() {
  var elements = document.getElementById('choices-multiple-remove-button');
  var param = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    param.push(elements[i].value);
  }
  console.log(param);
}

function hello() {
  var elements = document.getElementById('choices-multiple-remove-button');
  var param = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    param.push(elements[i].value);
  }
  console.log(param);
}
document.getElementById("workingbutton").addEventListener("click", hello);
```

```html
<button id="next" class="btn btn-info" onclick="next()" type="button">Next</button>
<button id="workingbutton" class="btn btn-info" type="button">Next</button>
```

Comment: You can find your question well explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick

Comment: "Best practice", particularly in the case of web dev, is often a heavily opinionated subject. If you don't have special needs (such as IE), pick whichever makes you feel the most comfortable and is the most suited to your use-case.

Comment: I'd personally go with the "hello" one, so all the js stays in one place. Some people like to see in the html when something has a js handler on it, so I usually add attributes like "data-js-submit" and then use that as a selector in js

Comment: People will say `addEventListener` is better

Comment: @pavelbere, both your comments point to the  same link.

Comment: @Krishna Prashatt that's because i commented and flagged XD